# SBT cannot find hadoop-aws 3.1.1

Tags: scala, hadoop, amazon-s3, sbt

`build.sbt`: (snippet)

```
val hadoop_aws  = "org.apache.hadoop"%  "hadoop-aws"       % "3.1.1"
libraryDependencies += hadoop_aws
```

But, when trying to `sbt update`:

```
> update
[info] Updating ...
[warn]  module not found: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-aws;3.1.1
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn] ==== sbt-maven-releases: tried
[warn] ==== sbt-maven-snapshots: tried
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn] ==== sbt-ivy-snapshots: tried
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-aws;3.1.1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.1.1 (/Users/me/project/build.sbt#L18-19)
[warn]        +- com.company:project_2.11:5bbf9d74
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-aws;3.1.1: not found
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.resolveAndRetrieve(IvyActions.scala:332)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$updateEither$1(IvyActions.scala:208)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.$anonfun$withModule$1(Ivy.scala:239)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.$anonfun$withIvy$1(Ivy.scala:204)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.sbt$internal$librarymanagement$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:70)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:95)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:80)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:99)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:60)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:50)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:199)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:196)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:238)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:193)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.ivy.IvyDependencyResolution.update(IvyDependencyResolution.scala:20)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:56)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:45)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:93)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:68)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$19(LibraryManagement.scala:106)
[error]     at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:224)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:106)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:89)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChanged$1(Tracked.scala:149)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:120)
[error]     at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask$5(Defaults.scala:2550)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:67)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:269)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:278)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:269)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-aws;3.1.1: not found
```

However, this module exists on maven-central, and sbt 1.2.3 (near as I can tell) checks maven central by default.

I'm not sure how to fix this or what to try next; everything else I've found on this looks to be solving the same error in sbt v0.13 by adding Maven as a resolver, but nothing for sbt v1.2.3, and nothing other than adding the (AFAIK) already-present Maven central resolver.

Comment: Did you try to invoke the binary compatibility through the `%%`? I mean like this:
`"org.apache.hadoop" %%  "hadoop-aws"  % "3.1.1"`

Comment: I can give that a go. It seems to be working with `2.8.3` instead of `3.1.1`, but I still don't know why, and I just kind of stumbled on which version, instead of actually finding anything out.

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to reproduce this error using the following build with sbt 1.2.8:

```scala
ThisBuild / scalaVersion     := "2.12.8"
ThisBuild / version          := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
ThisBuild / organization     := "com.example"
ThisBuild / organizationName := "example"

val hadoop_aws  = "org.apache.hadoop"%  "hadoop-aws"       % "3.1.1"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "hadoop",
    libraryDependencies += hadoop_aws
  )
```

Comment: Thanks, this should be helpful when I return to trying to resolve this.